# Change a variable name in queried javascript object

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, express

I have this query in express js:

```
connection.connect();

var queryString = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
if (err) throw err;

for(var i in rows){
rows[i].bestPrice = rows[i].MIN(inventory.price);
delete rows[i].MIN(inventory.price);
}


res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
res.end(JSON.stringify(rows););
});

connection.end();
```

It is querying some details about a laptop. The response JSON part looked like this before I added the for loop:

```
displayType: "LED"
vga: "Intel Graphics Media Accelerat"
partNumber: "A0100001"
MIN(inventory.price): "40000"
```

I want to change "MIN(inventory.price)" to "bestPrice", but it's not working. Any suggestion?

Comment: Post `queryString` here.

Comment: That's not really what the response JSON looks like, because that's not valid JSON.

Comment: its just a part of response JSON it s big I didnt want to copy the whole JSON file  and its formatted by postman application.

Comment: You could modify `queryString` for that.

Comment: I cant modify the query string because its collect a data from different tables, and its to large to add to here as a comment.

Comment: You need to use square bracket notation to access that key name.
rows[i].bestPrice = rows[i]['MIN(inventory.price)'];
delete rows[i]['MIN(inventory.price)'];

Comment: Ohh man big thanks for you, that was the exactly solution :) Write it to a post and I give you the answer marking :)